# Generalized inverse of matrix product involving a positive semi-definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following:
A real square positive definite matrix $A$, and a real square conformable positive semi-definite matrix $B$. I form the product

$$C = A^{-1}BA^{-1}$$

and I wonder, **is it true or not**, that

$$C^{-1} = C^{-}\overset{???}{=} \;\;AB^{-}A$$
Namely, does the rule $(EDF)^{-1} = F^{-1}D^{-1}E^{-1}$ for invertible square matrices continues to hold when generalized inverses are involved?
I searched several books as well as web resources (including math.se) but I could not find anything. Numerical examples with software show that it does hold, but I always prefer to have a theoretical proof -which appears to elude me, so I am posting this question.

Comment: It depends on what $B^{-}$ stands for. If it denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, then no, it is not generally true. It is easy to check that the [first two defining conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Definition) are true but the last two (symmetry) are not. In general, $(XY)^-=Y^-X^-$ if and only if $\mathcal{R}(X^*XY)\subseteq\mathcal{R}(Y)$ and $\mathcal{R}(YY^*X^*)\subseteq\mathcal{R}(X^*)$.

Comment: Maybe $B$ has a [Drazin inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drazin_inverse)?

Comment: @AlgebreicPavel Thank you I think this should be posted as an answer. Is there any reference you could give on such rules for generalized inverses? And no, I do not need $B^{-}$ to be the unique Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse.

Comment: @thanasissdr I could not say, I know the concept but I am not really familiar with it.

Comment: I don't know if [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379501006073) meets your needs at all, but in any case...

Comment: @thanasissdr The specific paper, no...  but the hosting site proposed also three related papers, which most probably contain what I need, as well as further related literature. So thanks!